# how to update developer facebook app version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, version, updates

my developer facebook book app give me an alert like this-

```
v2.9 Upgrade Reminder

Your App, とよたのりのりチャンネル, currently has access to 
Graph API v2.9 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime 
on 22 July, 2019. To ensure a smooth transition, please 
migrate all calls to Graph API v2.10 or higher. 
Use the API Upgrade Tool to understand exactly how this change will impact your app.

Note: If you do not see any impacted calls in the API Upgrade Tool,
 your app/code may not be affected by this upgrade.

Visit our changelog to see the full list of changes in all Graph 
API versions.
```

I checked `API Upgrade Tool` with the result-
[image]

I tried `Settings->Advance->Upgrade API Version` to v4.0 but this didn't update my app.

I keep getting warning-
[image]

How can I update my app?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings` > `Advanced`. You can upgrade the version over there. Also make sure to remove or replace version numbers in API calls in your code.

Comment: thank you but I already did that. and didn't solve my problem.

Comment: you did both? upgrading it in the app settings AND using new version numbers in your api calls?